# How to set policy according to Google's Strict CSP of Chrome Extension that is based on NextJS 14?

Tags: next.js, content-security-policy

I had created a Next.js project (version 14.1.0) with the "npx create-next-app@latest" command. After that, in the "public" directory, I created a 'manifest.json' file.:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "NextJs 14.1.0 Chrome Extension",
    "icons": {},
    "permissions": ["webNavigation"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```

And modified next.config.mjs by adding "output: 'export'":

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
};

export default nextConfig;
```

After uploading the build, everything is working fine except for errors that appeared after the first extension opening. These errors look like this:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-Q+8tPsjVtiDsjF/Cv8FMOpg2Yg91oKFKDAJat1PPb2g='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I was trying to add _document.tsx from this [article](https://dev.to/snaka/securing-your-nextjs-application-with-strict-csp-4lie) and middleware.ts from this [article](https://borstch.com/blog/development/nextjs-14s-content-security-policy-best-practices)
But it didnt help me, nothing changed